# htop - custom disk usage meter

Tags: linux, command-line-interface, htop

I was wondering if its possible to add custom meter to htop without the need to compile own modified binary. I am lacking meter that would show output of `df -h /`.

I know I can get that info via additional command or on my neofetch screen, but would preferably like to have it in one place along with other htop information.